# Perl one liner to seek to offset in file

Tags: perl, binaryfiles, one-liner

Is there a way to specify reading in file bytes that are at a position/offset within a binary file from the cmdline? (i.e. one-liners)
e.g.

```
perl -ne <...seek n bytes into file... do stuff...> inputfile
```

I haven't seen this and have tried using seek, sysseek, etc.

just want to experiment with `pack` and `unpack` by reading in a length of bytes at different offsets within a file.

**UPDATE**

In addition to the accepted answer, I just want to add the following equivalent answer but (to me) easier to remember+read

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{$/=undef, $offset=1, $len=2} print unpack("H*", substr($_, $offset, $len))' input
```

**UPDATE2**
For the purpose of doing hexdumps the following works

```
perl -0777 -ne '(printf "0x%02x ", $_) for (unpack "C*", substr($_, 0x1, 0x2))' input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
perl -M5.010 -0777ne'say unpack("N", substr($_, 0x20, 4))' inputfile
```

You're using `-n`, which reads a line of the file into `$_`. Binary files don't have lines, so we'll use `-0777` to tell Perl the treat the whole file as a line. Won't work in Windows since CRLF translation will occur.

---

For actual seeking,

```sh
perl -M5.010 -MFcntl=SEEK_SET -e'
   open(my $fh, "<:raw", $ARGV[0]) or die $!; 
   seek($fh, 0x20, SEEK_SET) or die $!;
   local $/ = \4;
   length( my $buf = <$fh> ) == 4 or die "Error";
   say unpack("N", $buf);
' inputfile
```

You can remove the line breaks if you want it all on one line.

Comment: Great! On mobile atm, but ill accept once im at computer and able to test.

Comment: Is there a way of putting space between each unpack unit in the output? `$\=" "` was not working for me. I want to get a hexdump style output.

Comment: Maybe using `split` someway?